# Current at 12 and 230 volts

Tags: power, batteries, formula-derivation

I hope someone can help explain this:

Say I have a `12 V 100 Ah` battery and a heater that uses `1000 watts`.

At 12 V we'll get `1000 / 12 = 83.3 amperes`, so the battery will last a little over 1 hr.

If I use an inverter to convert the `12 V` to `230 V` we get:

`1000 / 230 = 4.3 amperes`. Now the same battery will power the heater for 23 hrs.

How can the same battery have two different power levels? I must be doing something wrong.

Can someone explain my mistake please?

Comment: Aside from the answer given bij Hearth, in practice a 100 Ah battery will last far less than an hour at 83 A.

Comment: An inverter is not a free energy source. Energy out < energy in.

Comment: simpler mentally to compare watts so you don't have to consider amps or volts ratios.

Comment: If the inverter is 100% efficient, the power out equals the power in. If it is putting 1kW out, then it needs 1kW in, which, at 12V will correspond to the 83.3A.

Comment: It's worth being clear that your heater is only going to put out 1000W at its rated voltage.  A 230V 1000W heater connected to 12V won't even get hot enough to feel unless it's very compact (and any fan won't turn).  Conversely a 12V heater run at 230V will get very hot, and possibly very bright, but only for an instant (unless it catches fire)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Case 1:** Using a 12 V - 1 kW heater.

[image]

The heater draws 83.33 A from the battery.

**Case 2:** Using a 230 V - 1 kW heater and an inverter.

[image]

The heater draws 4.35 A from the inverter which, in turn, draws 83.33 A from the battery (assuming 100 % inverter efficiency).

The error is in presuming that only 4.35 A is drawn from the battery.

Answer (score 15):

The inverter passes power (voltage times current), not current, so a perfect inverter would still draw 83.3 amps from the battery.

Real inverters are not 100% efficient, so your inverter may draw close to 100 amps, and the battery voltage will drop somewhat when delivering that current, so the inverter will draw still more current.

The Ampere-hour rating of a lead-acid battery is based on a 20 hour discharge rate (5 A for a 100 Ah battery).  If you draw a higher current, you will get fewer than advertised Ah.  A table I have says that if you discharge a 100 Ah battery at 25 A, you will only get 72 Ah from it.

Answer (score 8):

The current through the load isn't what matters here; it's the current through the battery that matters. Assuming an ideal converter, the current through the battery in both cases will be identical and equal to 83.3 A.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to approach this kind of issues I found is to always reduce to power instead of using current/voltage.

In this case the battery has `12V x 100Ah = 1200Wh` of power, meaning that the heater can be turned on for `1200Wh/1000W = 1.2h`. Assuming everything ideal (ideal battery, ideal inverter etc...) this isn't going to change if you have an inverter in the middle.